Can everything in the bounded derived category of $k[x]/(x^2)$ be built in one step?
Consider the Artinian local ring $R=\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$.
Then, does there exist $G\in \text{D}^b(\text{mod } R)$ such that $ \text{D}^b(\text{mod } R)=\langle G \rangle_1$ ? Here, I am using the notation of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09SI.
Thoughts: Every finitely generated $R$-module is a finite direct sum of copies of $R$ and $R/(x)$. Hence, owing to  exact triangle $Z(X) \to X \to B(X)[1] \to  $ in $ \text{D}^b(\text{mod } R)$, we have $ \text{D}^b(\text{mod } R)=\langle R\oplus R/(x) \rangle_2$ ...

Some hints: What is the injective dimension of the $R$-module $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x)$? Recall that there exists an equivalence of categories $\textbf{D}^+(\text{mod R}) \simeq \textbf{K}^+(\mathcal{I})$, can you identify the full subcategory of $\textbf{K}^+(\mathcal{I}) $ which is equivalent to $\textbf{D}^b(\text{mod R}) $? This will help you identify the indescomposable objects in the bounded derived category.

@JavierHerrero: The injective dimension is $0$, but I'm not sure how does that or your other hints help ... if I'm not mistaken, my ring is the exterior algebra of $k$, so 4.1 of    https://www.math.ucla.edu/~rouquier/papers/repdim.pdf would seem to say that the Rouquier dimension is $1$; giving a negative answer to my question

$\mathbb{C}[x]/(x)$ is not an injective $R$-module, perhaps you should think more thoroughly this question. If you don’t know how to continue, I can try to give a more detailed solution but it is an interesting exercise to do by yourself.

@JavierHerrero: Agh sorry, I misread your comment to mean $\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$ ... $\mathbb C\cong \mathbb C[x]/(x)$ (the residue field) has infinite injective and projective dimension over $R$ ... but that shouldn't have any bearing to Rouquier's result I mentioned

I am thinking perhaps in a more “elementary” solution to what you’re asking (since it is possible to give a complete description of $\textbf{D}^b(\text{mod R})$ in this situation). If later I have some spare time, I’ll take a look to the result you have shared.
